# Matlab create image from array and save without displaying

Tags: image, matlab

Apologies if this is a dupe, I've been searching for over an hour but the search terms are all really broad and I just keep getting the same results. Also I'm fairly new to matlab so apologies for any misunderstandings.

Anywho, I have a matlab program which needs to frequently save an image generated from a matrix, but I just can't figure out how to do that without displaying it first. Basically I'm caught in between two functions, `image` and `imwrite`, both only do half of what I want.

`image` is able to take my matrix and create the desired output, but it just displays it to a figure window

[image: Output from <code>image</code> function]

`imwrite` is able to save an image to a file without displaying it, but the image is completely wrong and I can't find any parameters that would fix it.

[image: Output from <code>imwrite</code> function on same input]

Other questions I've seen deal with using `imread` and managing figures and stuff, but I'm just doing (for example)

```
matrix = rand(20);
colormap(winter);
image(matrix, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
```

or

```
matrix = rand(20);
imwrite(matrix, winter(256), 'filename.png');
```

Is there some way to call the `image` function such that it doesn't display a figure window and then gets saved to a file? Something analogous to calling `imshow` and then `savefig` in matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
matrix = rand(20);
f = figure('visible', 'off');
colormap(winter);
image(matrix, 'CDataMapping', 'scaled');
print(f, '-dpng', 'filename.png');
```